# Using indexOf (C#) to remove a set of characters from a string

Tags: c#

```
    public static string shita1(string st1)
    {
        string st2 = "", stemp = st1;
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<stemp.Length; i++)
        {

            if (stemp.IndexOf("cbc") == i)
            {
                i += 2 ;
                stemp = "";
                stemp = st1.Substring(i);
                i = 0;
            }
            else
                st2 = st2 + stemp[i];
        }
        return st2;
    }




    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string st1;
        Console.WriteLine("enter one string:");
        st1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(shita1(st1));
    }


}
```

i got a challange from my college, the challange is to move any "cbc" characters from a string...

this is my code... it works when i use only one "cbc" but when i use 2 of them it stucks... help please :)

Comment: what about `string result = input.replace("cbc", string.Empty);`?

Answer (score 1):

The IndexOf Method gives you everything you need to know.
Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of a specified
>   Unicode character or string within this instance. The method returns
>   -1 if the character or string is not found in this instance.

This means you can create a loop that repeats as long as the returned index is not -1 and you don't have to loop through the string testing letter by letter.

Comment: so how can i remove more than one "cbc" set of characters from one string?

Comment: Since this is for school, I'll leave the specifics of that up to you.  But take a look at what you know already. 1. How find where "cbc" appears. 2. How to know when "cbc" is not present. 3.  How to remove one set of "cbc" from the string.  4. How to loop.  You already have all the tools you need.  I have faith in you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work just tested it on some examples. Doesn't use string.Replace or IndexOf

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter one string:");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(RemoveCBC(input));
        }

        static string RemoveCBC(string source)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i + 2 == source.Length)
                    break;

                var c = source[i];
                var b = source[i + 1];
                var c2 = source[i + 2];

                if (c == 'c' && c2 == 'c' && b == 'b')
                    i = i + 2;
                else
                    result.Append(source[i]);
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Replace` to remove/replace all occurances of a string inside another string:

```
string original = "cbc_STRING_cbc";
original = original.Replace("cbc", String.Empty);
```

Comment: That would be the easiest way to do it, but does not conform to the challenge as assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove characters from string using only IndexOf method you can use this code.

```
public static string shita1(string st1)
    {
        int index = -1;
        string yourMatchingString = "cbc";
        while ((index = st1.IndexOf(yourMatchingString)) != -1)
            st1 = st1.Remove(index, yourMatchingString.Length);
        return st1;
    }
```

This code remove all inputs of you string.

But you can do it just in one line:

```
st1 = st1.Replace("cbc", string.Empty);
```

Hope this help.